# Google Drive not working on LG TV

Tags: google-drive

I tried to open Google Drive on LG TV (model: LG webOS TV UJ7507), but I got a message that says that the browser on TV cannot support Google Drive and needs to be updated. The problem is that the update is not possible because firstly there is no Google Chrome app in LG's app store and secondly the option to download/update Chrome somewhere from the internet isn't supported by LG's operating system. Until today, I was able to normally access Drive on this TV.

How to access Drive from the built-in browser as before, because I can't install Chrome or any other browser on my TV?

Comment: What is the question? Have you already reviewed the [system requirements](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375082?hl=en)?

Comment: Yes, I read it all. I've just added what the specific question is in the text above.